# The Cantor set is nowhere dense

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am considering the so called **Cantor ternary set** $C$ on $[0,1]$. I have just proved that its Lebesgue measure is $0$. 
To show that $C$ is nowhere dense, is it correct the following reasoning?

> By contradiction, let's suppose there exists an open set contained in $C$. Without loss of generality, assume $\exists\,x_0\in[0,1]$ and $r>0$ such that the open ball $B(x_0,r)\subseteq C$. Then, by monotonicity of the Lebesgue measure $L^1$, we have that $L^1(B(x_0,r))=0$, which is an absurd.

Comment: Did you prove that $C$ is closed? Nowhere dense means that the *closure* has empty interior. Your proof is OK as long as you show that $C$ is closed.

Comment: Yes, I proved also that $C$ is closed

Comment: Your reasoning in correct. You can argue as follows as well: Whatever $r>0$ you pick, there is an $n$ large enough that $1/3^n <r$. Verify, directly from the recursive construction of $C$, that it contains no interval of length $1/3^n$. This shows that $B(x_0,r)$ is not contained in $C$.